# Could SQL performance be increased by storing rotations of the data?

Tags: sql, php, mysql

I'm working on a project where this kind of SQL Psuedocode would apply:

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE (distance
```

My inputs are latitude and longitude, and my database holds latitude and longitude.

One solution that I have seen is to use a command like the following to produce a square shaped output

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE (latitude BETWEEN center-distance AND center+distance) AND (longitude BETWEEN center-distance AND center+distance)
```

Then have the program shave off the corners of the square.

Does anyone know if it would perform well to make 2 extra rotations of the data and search by that? The output would be a 12-sided object. It may look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE(latitude BETWEEN a1 AND a2) AND (longitude BETWEEN b1 AND b2) AND (latitude_r1 BETWEEN a1_r1 AND a2_r1) AND (longitude_r1 BETWEEN b1_r1 AND b2_r1) AND (latitude_r2 BETWEEN a1_r2 AND a2_r2) AND (longitude_r2 BETWEEN b1_r2 AND b2_r2)
```

So, for example, no added rotations would make a square, 1 extra rotation would make an octogon (8 sided), 2 extra rotations 12, 3 extra rotations 16, meaning each additional rotation would increase accuracy, but I don't know if the additional indexes would cost more or less than the gains per a rotation.

So, assuming that creating the rotated data set and creating the rotated search terms were free, would this be a viable method to estimate objects within X distance? In my situation, performance is more important than 99% accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best performance would be obtained by storing the location as a point geometry (longitude,latitude), building a spatial index, and using a search shape which is geodetically correct (an egg-shaped 'circle', which is the search distance deprojected into a geographic reference system).  37 vertices is more than enough points to achieve 99% of the area, but vertex count probably won't hurt performance until you reach 3601 points.  I converted [US Geodetic Survey FORTRAN code](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/Inv_Fwd/) to 'C' and Java long ago, but there are many ways to generate the spherical search polygon.

The biggest problem is dealing with search shapes which cross the antimeridian, since you need to either split the search shape at 180 degrees east/west (which will negatively impact the search efficiency), or search both sides (by shifting the shape 360 degrees west/east on successive queries).

Comment: So, I guess my idea was bad because the Earth is not a perfect sphere?

Comment: That's part of it, but the other aspect is not making use of available technology -- This problem has already been solved with a point-in-polygon algorithm.